# Javascript Functions not Functioning

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, onclick

I've been instructed to make a simple game in which click on an image increases your score and eventually allows upgrades. When I click the image, it displays the amount of clicks left the first time, however, subsequent times do not seem to work. Is this a problem with how my functions call each other?

**Javascript**

```
//Variables
var clicks = 0;
var level = 2;
var clickInterval = 1;
var holdClick = 0;

function imgClicked() { //Activated by clicking on image
    var clicks = clicks + clickInterval; //Increasing clicks
    upgradeCheck();
    if (holdClick === 1) { //If holding down the image activated
        window.onmousedown = holding();
    }
}

function upgradeCheck() { //Check if eligible for new level
    if (clicks > Math.pow(level, 2)) { //If clicks more than current level^2
        level = level + 1; //Next level
        upgrade();

    } else { //If not
        var clicksLeft = Math.pow(level, 2) - clicks; //Determine clicks until eligible
        document.getElementById("toUpgrade").innerHTML = clicksLeft + " clicks left until upgrade"; //Display
    }
}

function upgrade() { //Upgrading
    document.getElementById("clickImg").src = "level" + level + ".png"; //Change to new level
    var clickInterval = clickInterval * 2; //Increase points per click
    if (Math.pow(level, 2) / clickInterval > 400) { //If it take more than 400 clicks to get to next level
        var holdClick = 1; //Activate hold clicking
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "You can now hold down the image";
    }
}

function holding() {
    var clicks = clicks + clickInterval; //Adding more clicks
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="toUpgrade"></p>
<img id="clickImg" src="level2.png" onclick="imgClicked()" />
<p> id="message"></p>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is doing what you think it's doing:

```
var clicks = clicks + clickInterval; //Adding more clicks
```

You're not modifying the global `clicks` variable, you're creating an *entirely new* variable called `clicks` only within the scope of that function.  Then that variable goes away when the function completes.  You never actually modify the existing `clicks` variable.  I think you want this instead:

```
clicks = clicks + clickInterval; //Adding more clicks
```

The same mistake is made elsewhere, such as:

```
var clickInterval = clickInterval * 2; //Increase points per click
```

and:

```
var holdClick = 1; //Activate hold clicking
```

Remove the `var` keywords to prevent declaring new variables.